# Meaning of '@' in "@set -e" command in Makefiles

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu

In Makefile, in commands of the form

`all:
        @set -e; \
        do more stuff`

I know the set -e commands the shell to to exit on failure. What is the significance of the `@` attached to `set`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a Makefile, the `@` symbol means that the command is not echoed to the screen when it is run.

Comment: Thanks. Only the command to which it is sticked or also the commands following it?

Comment: Only the command after the `@`.

Comment: It applies to the entire _logical line_ in the recipe.  In your example you have used a backslash to combine two physical lines into a single logical line, so neither of those two commands (the `set -e` or the `do more stuff`) will be echoed.  If you add another recipe line that is not connected to these with a backslash/newline, then that command _will_ be echoed.  Just try adding and removing the `@` and see what happens.