# How to use shell script in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

```
all:
    @for dir in $(DIRS); do make -C $$dir; done
```

I can't understand symbol `@`. Why use `@` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610799/what-does-at-symbol-colon-mean-in-a-makefile

Comment: Searching for `@` in the make manual would have been a good start too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of '@' in "@set -e" command in Makefiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400830/meaning-of-in-set-e-command-in-makefiles)

Answer (score 0):

It just avoids echoing the command... [Google is your friend](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html)